# Java Reflection checking String fields length

Tags: java, reflection

There is a method:

```
    public List<Field> getAtLeastTenChar(Object o) {

 List<Field> FieldList = new ArrayList<>();
     Class c = o.getClass();
     Field[] mezok = c.getFields();
     for(int i=0; i<mezok.length; i++){
     if(mezok[i].getType()==String){
     if(mezok[i].length()>10){
     FieldList.add(mezok[i])
     }
     }
     }
}
```

If `o` has String fields, I want to know, are these strings length reaches 10 character. 
If yes it puts these fields to the List end at the and returns the List. 
I think it could be done with reflection, but not sure about how to.

Comment: This question is rather unclear... Could you be more specific?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all yet?

Comment: So you didn't try anything?

Comment: Are you saying you want to use reflection, to find if the passed object has getters returning Strings? And then if those Strings are atleast 10 characters?

Comment: Get the class of the objects, then the fields of the class, then their value from the object. The javadoc is there to help.

Comment: I don't think you understand what reflection is or what it's meant to be used for...

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, it was a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Class<?> objClass = o.getClass();
Field[] fields = objClass.getDeclaredFields();
List<Field> fieldList = new LinkedList<Field>();
for(Field field : fields) { 
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Object value = field.get(o);
    if(value instanceof String)
        if(((String) value).length() > 10){
            fieldList.add(field);
        }               
  }
 }
 return fieldList;
```

would do what you want, it takes the declared fields checks to see if its instance of String if it is, it checks if the length is greater then 10 then adds the field to a linkedlist.

The code is untested fyi and written on the fly